# How to loop in a table using DAX / Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the next table in Power BI:

| Id | Old Id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 |  |
| 5 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 7 | 6 |
| 8 | 7 |

The column **Id** is the identifier of a product that last 1 month, if the product is updated then a new Id is created after a month, **Old Id** column shows the previous Id that the product had, where the product comes from.

What I am trying to get is that based on the sequence of ***Old Id***, try to identify the last ***Id*** that belongs to the original ID as is showed in this table:

| Id | Old Id | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 2 |  |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |
| 6 |  | 8 |
| 7 | 6 |  |
| 8 | 7 |  |

I am working in DAX, so I have read that looping is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach:

Add new column to your table as:

> PathIt = PATHITEM(PATH(Sheet2[Id],Sheet2[Old Id]), 1)

Next create a new measure:

> LastID = CALCULATE( max(Sheet2[Id]), ALL(Sheet2), TREATAS( {
> SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet2[Id]) }, Sheet2[PathIt] ))

[image]